# Continuous deployment tools for varying platforms, middleware, technologies, with metrics and reporting

Tags: deployment, release-management, web-deployment, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

What are some comparable continuous deployment tools to UrbanCode uDeploy, Noliosoft ZeroTouch, and XebiaLabs Deployit? The environment I am trying to deploy apps to is multi-OS (Linux, Windows Server), various types of middleware (Websphere, Weblogic, Jboss, Tomcat, Apache, IIS, BizTalk), different databases (Oracle, MySQL, MSSQL), and includes different types of application packaging (.war, .jar, .conf, .xml, .zip, .exe, .msi). I am also pulling from filesystems instead of Maven repositories (but in the future will need to integrate with Maven). I have built a Maven-cargo deployment process but the deployment engineers would like a GUI based tool with metrics gathering. I've tried a Webistrano deployment but can't get .NET, IIS and .msi deployments to work properly (I know - its not meant for those platforms). I have Red Hat JON but it does not allow for deployments to Windows. SCCM?  Glu? OctopusDeploy? Kwatee?

Comment: Kwatee does a pretty long way but currently lacks msi deployment. It's something that we are looking into

Comment: Steve if you end up with questions on uDeploy feel free to contact me directly at eric@urbancode.com. I'm also happy to give you the lay of the competitive landscape as we see it.